# Get list of Window in Selenium (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, window-handles

[image]

I thought initially that I could retrieve Chrome Windows by using

```
var windows = await driver.getAllWindowHandles();
```

Problem with that is that it doesn't actually get Chrome "Window" but Tabs. Is there anyway in Selenium to have a concept of real "visual" Chrome window? I want to know if a Tab is from a specific Window and how many tabs in a Window specifically. The doc is misleading especially with getAllWindowHandles which implies that it's about Window.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally there is no significant difference between a *Tab* and a *Window*. The only difference is how it is being presented to an user.

At the core, each *Tab* as well as each *Window* can have a totally separate [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) and it's own [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) environment.

### Get Window Handles

As per the [specs](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dfn-get-window-handles):

[image: Get Window Handles]

> The order in which the window handles are returned is arbitrary.
>
> The remote end steps are:
>
> - Let handles be a JSON List.
> - For each top-level browsing context in the remote end, push the associated window handle onto handles.
> - Return success with data handles.

---

### Conclusion

To conclude from [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) perspective both *Tab* and *Window* are treated in the same way.

Comment: Thanks for the details, yeah It's what I thought after looking extensively every doc possible... I find it honestly surprising that no-one ever thought of having a concept of Window while it's definitely available in browsers since forever. Really surprising